# Content-Security-Policy denies my usage of JS inline modules on local subdomain

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

I'm developing a service with subdomain architecture, but my requests for JS modules gets blocks with any Content-Security-Policy I try (even with just `*`).

Current URL: `http://cod.boardmeister.local/`

My head:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' *.boardmeister.local"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./media/style/dist/output.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./media/style/imports.css">
```

JS:

```js
<script type="module">
      import * as components from './components.js';
</script>
```

Error:
`Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”).`

I'm using NGINX and Firefox.

Also, when I try to import module as an external source:

```html
<script type="module" src="./components.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I'm getting `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://components.boardmeister.local/dito.min.js (“default-src”).`

My `components.js`

```js
import config from './config.js';

const { Dito } = await import(config.components_url + 'dito.min.js');
```

Comment: To use `<script>` tags with content you need `'unsafe-inline'`

Comment: @mousetail `default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'` ? If so I'm getting the same error

Comment: It will just let you run inline scripts like the first example

Comment: @mousetail I understand, just letting you know that even after adding it and trying to load module inline I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my NGINX config was setting Content-Security-Policy header which overwrote my own set in browser. This is the one that worked for my case:

```html
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' *.boardmeister.local; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' *.boardmeister.local; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"/>
```